# Header View title getting overwritten with Inherited controller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationbar, subclassing, qheaderview

I am trying to access the properties and objects that are declared in one view controller in to the page where I need them.Did so by subclassing the view controller.But I have got a problem here,the   inherited controller is making the controller overwritten.I mean the navigation bar and header view of the subclassed controller is getting displayed in the used view.When I remove the [super viewDidLoad] method,the vlaues which needs to be displayed is not getting displayed.Also the header view of the inherited view controller is getting displayed.I did subclassing using the following statement:I am also posting the code:

```
ERViewEditController class:

    @interface ERViewEditController:ERAddReminderController
    {

        UITableView *theTable;

    }

    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *theTable;

    @end

    @implementation ERViewEditController

    // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
         self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.jpg"]];
         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(pop:)];
         self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(edit:)];

         [self setTitle:@"Reminders Listed"];

         [self.theTable reloadData];
         [super viewDidLoad];
     }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)view cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        NSString *CellId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[view dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];

        UILabel *label1 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(54, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
        label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UILabel *label2 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(119, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
        label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UILabel *label3 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(198, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
        label3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellId] autorelease];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderbutton.png"]];

            if (indexPath.section == 0) 
            {
                UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 3, 280, 40)]autorelease];
                label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label.text = @" ID   Name     Event          Date";
                label.textColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
                [cell addSubview:label];
            }   

            else if (indexPath.section == 1)
            {
                const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
                sqlite3_stmt *statement;

                if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &remindersDB) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name,event,date FROM reminders"];

                    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(remindersDB ,query_stmt , -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                        {
                            NSString *nameField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

                            NSString *eventField = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];                    

                            NSString *dateField = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];

                            [nameField stringByAppendingString:eventField];

                            label1.text = nameField;
                            label2.text = eventField;
                            label3.text = dateField;
                        } 

                        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                    }
                    sqlite3_close(remindersDB);
                }

                switch (indexPath.row) 
                {
                    case 0:
                        [cell addSubview:label1];
                        [cell addSubview:label2];
                        [cell addSubview:label3];
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }

        }

        return cell;

    }


My navigation bar issue is resolved,now I have still been facing the header view title issue,I used the following code to fix:

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"";
}
```

but not working,please help me to get out of this,thanks Mr.Ben for the answer :)

Also I have another problem,please check that too if possible,thanks in advance :)

[Populate the table view sections with rows of table in sqlite database in an order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475446/generating-cells-automatically-to-display-saved-reminder-values-of-database-in-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is a bit confusing, but it sounds like your superclass is setting a title/button information after you set it in the subclass. Re-order your viewDidLoad so the [super viewDidLoad]; is first in the function, any subclass changes will then be applied after the superclass sets it.

Comment: Ben Yeah I understood,thanks for the answer,that worked perfect for navigation bar issue.But the header view is still getting overwritten with inherited view controller,please help me to resolve that issue too!

Comment: Please see the edited answer and screen shot Mr.Ben,thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ben I found out the solution why header view of inherited controller is getting displayed...

Since the view controller is subclassed all the feature like navigation bar,header view etc.. will appear,hence we need to implement all the methods of super class,i.e.

As I have implemented - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section in inherited controller with titles,

We need to implement the same method and simply return nil which will fix the issue

Anyway thanks a ton for the patience and response to my question,Thanks once again...bye TC.