# Populate the table view sections with rows of table in sqlite database in an order

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sqlite

I have 2 view controller pages.Add Reminder page which contains save button as right bar button of navigation bar

I have earlier got issues regarding number of sections in table view for view reminder page based on number of saves in add reminder page:

I found out the solution for generating cells based on number of saved reminders

this is the code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)view
{
NSInteger numTableRecords = -1;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &remindersDB) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select count(*) from reminders"];
        const char *sql = [sqlStatement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(remindersDB, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {          
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                numTableRecords = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("could not prepare statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(remindersDB));
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in Opening Database File");
    }
    sqlite3_close(remindersDB);
    return numTableRecords; 
}
```

Now my problem here is I am able to retrieve the data,but not in a proper way.I mean this is the code I used to retrieve the data

```
if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellId] autorelease];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderbutton.png"]];

        label1 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(26, 3, 30, 40)]autorelease];
        label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        label2 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
        label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        label3 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(119, 3, 100, 40)]autorelease];
        label3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        label4 = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(198, 3, 120, 40)]autorelease];
        label4.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label4.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        //Retrieve the values of database
        const char *dbpath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &remindersDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from reminders ORDER BY id"];

            const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.remindersDB ,query_stmt , -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    NSString *ID = [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]autorelease];

                    NSString *nameField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]autorelease];                    

                    NSString *eventField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]autorelease];

                    NSString *dateField = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]autorelease];

                    label1.text = ID;
                    label2.text = nameField;
                    label3.text = eventField;
                    label4.text = dateField;
                } 

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
            sqlite3_close(self.remindersDB);
        }


                    [cell addSubview:label1];
                    [cell addSubview:label2];
                    [cell addSubview:label3];
                    [cell addSubview:label4];

    }

    return cell;
```

I have inserted 4 reminders,the 4 cells are appearing,but the problem is with displaying

It is appearing as following

[image]

How can I get the 4 reminders displayed in 4 cells consecutively,I mean the 1st reminder on 1st,2nd reminder on 2nd and so on..

Please help me to fix this issue,thanks all in advance :)

Sorry all...I found out the complete solution to the issue in the following link:

[Retrieve all rows inserted in sqlite database and display in table view cells containing labels as subviews with different sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574342/retrieve-all-rows-inserted-in-sqlite-database-and-display-in-table-view-cells-co)

Sorry for the question...Thanks every one who viewed this,take it If useful

Hence I am not removing this question,bye TC :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm giving you one suggestion just try it. I hope it will work.

Do one thing, just retrieve data from sqlite in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` and save the data in an nsmutableArray.

Then in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` just return [yourArray count].

and for reloading table just try with `[self.tableview reloadData]`

I hope it'll be work. just let me know for any further clarification.

Comment: one small doubt where should I place reload Data statement and how to display the retrieved data,shall I use labels as I did before

Comment: I implemented what you suggested,but the table view is appearing a plane back ground with header view titles of Add reminder page,please help me where I did worng

Comment: did you make background color clear?yah you can use label and add to cell.contentview

Comment: your number of cell problem is solved or not. [self.tableview reloadData] should be written on save button click method  .

Comment: you try for the day if not done then i'll clarify tomorrow. I'm leaving for the day. Bye have a good.

Comment: I have actually subclassed the view controller i.e add reminder to access the database and path for view reminder controller.So I have earlier faced the problem of overwritten of navigation bar and header view titles,I have made table view back ground as clear color in add reminder page,but not in view reminder page

Comment: Actually the cells are not appearing,the view itself is blank with stripes and of course header view titles of the add reminder view

Comment: Please see the above post,I wrote [tableView reloadData] at save action only,but its not coming,let me edit the question to make it clear and what I did that you suggested

Comment: Please see the above edited answer for clear understanding,anyway thanks for the patience and concern,bye take care :)

Comment: Hay da, for making cell with that required color just write the following code in

Comment: What is that code,please tell me buddy
Actually cells are not getting displayed as you can see in screen shot that header view titles of add reminder page are displayed on the view with black lines once see the edited answer

Comment: Yeah,just send the mail,please check it out

Comment: Sandy Hi...have you seen my project,I have sent u mail

Comment: hay eshwar today I back to office and saw ur code. Can u please specify me which class I need to check?

Comment: Sandy Please check the ERAddReminder group as well as ERViewEdit group classes which will be visible when you open the code and expand classes group.Please once run the code and you can see the header view titles getting displayed from add reminder controller in view reminder controller page.....Anyway I fixed the issue today!

My requirement is I want cells to be added automatically in view reminder page when I click save in add reminder page,If you can help me in acheiving that,I would be very glad and thankful to you

Thanks in advance and concern once again :)

Comment: Sandy Hi Sandy,sorry for the interruption.....What is the status of my code

Did you get some free time to check it out...Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Sandy .... Hi there any solution regarding my problem,sorry for interrupting again and again,I am pretty much thankful to you for what all the help and care shown for my sake till now :)

Comment: Sandy Hi sandy I have found out the solution for generation of cells depending on number of saved reminders.

See the edited answer,the only issue to be solved now is arrange the reminders in an order i.e. 1st reminder on 1st cell,2nd on 2nd cell and so on...please help me on that point

Comment: sandy Hi Mr.Sandy please give me an update about the status,I have been waiting for your reply,thanks :)

Comment: Hay Eshwar for arrange the reminders in an order i.e. 1st reminder on 1st cell,2nd on 2nd cell and so on, you do one thing. I hope you are taking all data from database in a array right? now in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)view cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { ,method write the following: label1.text=[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]; don't do again what y are doing still. i told u take all data in an array. then try.

Comment: Oh sure sandy,thanks for the suggestion,ll try and get back to you,Thanks once again :)

Comment: Yeah sandy,did what you suggested but not working shall I send the updated code to your mail...I did what all you suggested,thanks for the patience :)

Comment: Sandy I have mailed you my updated project,please check it out

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sandy sorry for the trouble.... Yeah I will not repeat it once again please download my project and remove the mail I have sent,I am not gonna trouble you any more...

Have you seen my code anyway,thanks :)

Comment: Give me sometime I'll check, Thanx

Comment: Thank you so much...

I owe a lot to you,thanks once again for everything,bye TC:)

Comment: Sandy ... sorry for the trouble and for wasting your valuable time,I found out the solution in this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574342/retrieve-all-rows-inserted-in-sqlite-database-and-display-in-table-view-cells-co

Sorry once again,thanks for spending time for fixing my issue..bye TC :)

Answer (score 1):

for making cell with that required color just write the following code in

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:@"Give your cell image"]
```

in `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)view cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
  method and not in condition, outside the condition you should put it. and why you do database work in this method. it will slow your apps. let me know for any clarification.

Comment: Hei I am actually very thankful for the patience and response for my question from 2 days,actually I did what all you suggested,its not coming,shall I place the zip file of my project so that the communication gap can be filled

Comment: Also for better understanding of problem

Comment: The o/p remains the same as in screen shot you can see above

Comment: The one with blank background and with values of header view titles of add reminder view

Comment: Now I have made changes,I took a method -(void)getData and wrote code for retrieving data from database and took labels to display in cells of table view.Then I called the [self getData] method in viewDidAppear method and then called [self.tableView reloadData],the cells are not getting displayed,that's the problem please see the first screen shot and compare with other two

Comment: Sorry I was in meeting that's why did not give answer.yah sure u can put.

Comment: Please give your mail id so that I can send my project

Comment: Because I don't know how to place zip file in this site

Comment: Yeah here is the link of my project please download and check it out when ever you are free,thanks for the patience once again :)

http://www.filefactory.com/file/c0b8c72/n/EventsReminder.zip

Comment: The download link will be at the bottom of the page

Comment: click slow download,there we need to enter captcha code and then again we need to click download,which will be indicated with red arrow,please let me know whether it is working or not